# how change page class parameter on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have A ASP.NET page Parameter named `NumberOfSelect` , how can I change This Parameter on PostBack ?
i want to increase number of selected Items when a user click on a button.
but after postback it has 0 value!

```
    public partial class FetchOnDemand : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int NumberOfSelect=0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            NumberOfSelect = 20;

        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
        string strSql = "Select TOP " + NumberOfSelect + " * From Comment_Table";
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dap.Fill(dt);
        tblOrders.DataSource = dt;
        tblOrders.DataBind();
    }
    protected void hiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumberOfSelect = NumberOfSelect + 10;


    }
}
```

Comment: This is expected since you are not persisting/storing the value somewhere. remember, HTTP is stateless. you could render the NumberOfSelected as a hidden field, then when it gets posted, you can read it from the Request.Form[] parameters to see what the last value was and increment it or whatever and write it back to the hidden field ready for the next request.

Comment: Each request to a page, whether or not it's a post-back, is a *new* request, which means that your `FetchOnDemand` class is reinstantiated on every request, resetting your private field to `0`. You should store the value in `ViewState` manually or use an `<asp:HiddenField />` control to store the value.

Comment: Thank You , i got it, i will use a label or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each request to a page, whether or not it's a post-back, is a *new* request, which means that your `FetchOnDemand` class is reinstantiated on every request, resetting your private field to `0`. You should store the value in `ViewState` manually or use an `<asp:HiddenField />` control to store the value.

Here's the `ViewState` approach. Instead of using a private field, set up a property that can read and write to the `ViewState`:

```
protected int NumberOfSelect
{
   get
   {
      return (int)ViewState["NumberOfSelect"];
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["NumberOfSelect"] = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri: Thanks, glad it helped. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! If this was a good solution to your issue then please make sure to accept it by clicking the green check mark to the left.